# Restore standard Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation functionality in top navigation for a single website in a multi-store Magento installation

Tags: php, magento

I'm currently working on a Magento installation with multiple websites and store views. I'm attempting to redesign one of the four sub websites.

There has been a custom module added which appears to rewrite/extend the default top navigation menu to automatically include CMS pages and add a banner slot to the menu. The problem is that I want to restore the **default Magento top menu** (i.e. no CMS pages) for a single website view.

I've tried disabling the module inside System -> Config -> Advanced -> Advanced for that website, however this seems to make the entire top navigation disappear. I believe the function I want to remove is this:

```
<?php
/**
 * extend functions from navigation.php
 * 
 */
class Fvzzy_Category_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation
{
    protected $_menus;

    protected function _getCategoryMenuItemHtml($category, $level = 0, $isLast = false, $isFirst = false,
        $isOutermost = false, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $noEventAttributes = false)
    {
        if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
            return '';
        }
        $html = array();

        // get all children
        if (Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat')->isEnabled()) {
            $children = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
            $childrenCount = count($children);
        } else {
            $children = $category->getChildren();
            $childrenCount = $children->count();
        }
        $hasChildren = ($children && $childrenCount);

        // select active children
        $activeChildren = array();
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            if ($child->getIsActive()) {
                $activeChildren[] = $child;
            }
        }
        $activeChildrenCount = count($activeChildren);
        $hasActiveChildren = ($activeChildrenCount > 0);

        // prepare list item html classes
        $classes = array();
        $classes[] = 'level' . $level;
        //$classes[] = 'nav-' . $this->_getItemPosition($level);
        $text = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/i', '-', strtolower($category->getName()));
        //$classes[] = $category->;
        if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
        }
        $linkClass = '';
        if ($isOutermost && $outermostItemClass) {
            $classes[] = $outermostItemClass;
            $linkClass = ' class="'.$outermostItemClass.'"';
        }
        if ($isFirst) {
            $classes[] = 'first';
        }
        if ($isLast) {
            //$classes[] = 'last';
        }
        if ($hasActiveChildren) {
            $classes[] = 'parent';
        }
        if(strtolower($text) == 'sale') $classes[] = strtolower($text);
        // prepare list item attributes
        $attributes = array();
        if (count($classes) > 0) {
            $attributes['class'] = implode(' ', $classes);
        }

        if ($hasActiveChildren && !$noEventAttributes) {
             $attributes['onmouseover'] = 'toggleMenu(this,1)';
             $attributes['onmouseout'] = 'toggleMenu(this,0)';
        }
        // assemble list item with attributes
        $htmlLi = '<li';
        foreach ($attributes as $attrName => $attrValue) {
            $htmlLi .= ' ' . $attrName . '="' . str_replace('"', '\"', $attrValue) . '"';
        }
        $htmlLi .= '>';
        $html[] = $htmlLi;

        $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
        $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
        $html[] = '</a>';

        // render children
        $htmlChildren = '';
        $j = 0;
        foreach ($activeChildren as $child) {
            $htmlChildren .= $this->_getCategoryMenuItemHtml(
                $child,
                ($level + 1),
                ($j == $activeChildrenCount - 1),
                ($j == 0),
                false,
                $outermostItemClass,
                $childrenWrapClass,
                $noEventAttributes
            );
            $j++;
        }
        $promotion = $this->addPromotions($category->getId());
        if (!empty($htmlChildren)) {
            if ($childrenWrapClass) {
                $html[] = '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
            }
            $html[] = '<ul class="level' . $level . '"><div class="menu-text">';
            if($promotion) $html[] = '';
            $html[] = $htmlChildren;
            if($promotion) $html[] = '';
            if($promotion) $html[] = '</div><li class="level1 parent menu-promotion">'.$promotion.'</li>';
            $html[] = '</ul>';
            if ($childrenWrapClass) {
                $html[] = '</div>';
            }
        }

        $html[] = '</li>';

        $html = implode("\n", $html);
        return $html;
    }

    public function renderCategoriesMenuHtml($level = 0, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '')
    {
        $activeCategories = array();
        foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $child) {
            if ($child->getIsActive()) {
                $activeCategories[] = $child;
            }
        }
        $activeCategoriesCount = count($activeCategories);
        $hasActiveCategoriesCount = ($activeCategoriesCount > 0);

        if (!$hasActiveCategoriesCount) {
            return '';
        }

        $html = '';
        $j = 0;
        foreach ($activeCategories as $category) {
            $html .= $this->_getCategoryMenuItemHtml(
                $category,
                $level,
                ($j == $activeCategoriesCount - 1),
                ($j == 0),
                true,
                $outermostItemClass,
                $childrenWrapClass,
                true
            );
            $j++;
        }
        //main store
        if(Mage::app()->getStore()) $html .= $this->addMenu($childrenWrapClass,Mage::app()->getStore());
        return $html;
    }

    protected function addPromotions($id = 0){
        if($id){
            $base = Mage::getBaseUrl('media',true).'promotion_box_images/';
            $file_base = Mage::getBaseDir('media').'/promotion_box_images';
            $html = ''; $img = '';
            $promotion = Mage::getModel('promotion/box')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('menu_ids',array(
                array('like'=>$id),
                array('like'=>$id.',%'),
                array('like'=>'%,'.$id.',%'),
                array('like'=>'%,'.$id)))->setOrder('position')->getFirstItem(); //default is desc
            if($promotion && $promotion->getId()){
                $type=$promotion->getDisplayType();
                $link = ''; $img = ''; $content = ''; $width = '';
                if(file_exists($file_base.'/'.$promotion->getImage())){
                    list($width) = getimagesize($file_base.'/'.$promotion->getImage());
                }
                if($type!=null){
                    switch($type){
                        case 0:
                            if($promotion->getImage()!='') $img = '<img src="'.$base.$promotion->getImage().'" alt="'.$promotion->getTitle().'" width="'.$width.'"/>';
                            if(trim($promotion->getLink())!='') $link = $promotion->getLink();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            if($promotion->getImage()!='') $img = '<img src="'.$base.$promotion->getImage().'" alt="'.$promotion->getTitle().'" width="'.$width.'"/>';
                            if($promotion->getCategoryId()){
                                $c = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($promotion->getCategoryId());
                                if($c->getId() && $c->getIsActive()) $link = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($c);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if($promotion->getImage()!='') $img = '<img src="'.$base.$promotion->getImage().'" alt="'.$promotion->getTitle().'" width="'.$width.'"/>';
                            if($promotion->getProductSku()){
                                $id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($promotion->getProductSku());
                                $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
                                if($p->getId()) $link = $p->getProductUrl();
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            if($promotion->getImage()!='') $img = '<img src="'.$base.$promotion->getImage().'" alt="'.$promotion->getTitle().'" width="'.$width.'"/>';
                            if($promotion->getPageId()){
                                $_link = Mage::Helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl($promotion->getPageId());
                                                                if($_link != ''){ 
                                                                $nodes = Mage::getModel('enterprise_cms/hierarchy_node')->getCollection()
                                                                  ->addFieldToFilter('page_id', array('eq' => $promotion->getPageId()));
                                                            foreach($nodes as $_node){
                                                                $link = $_node->getRequestUrl();
                                                            }
                                                            if(!$link){$link = Mage::Helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl($promotion->getPageId());}
                                                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            $content = $promotion->getContent();
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if($img && $link){
                    $html = '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$img.'</a>';
                }
                elseif($img){
                    $html = '<a href="">'.$img.'</a>';
                }
                else{
                    $html = $content;
                }
            }
            return $html;
        }else{return false;}
    }

    //$menu = array( array('label'=>'News','href'=>'blog','module'=>'blog','sub'=>array(array('label'=>'submenu','href'=>'blog2','module'=>'blog'))) );
    public function setOtherMenu($menu){
        $this->_menus = $menu;
    }

    public function addMenu( $childrenWrapClass = '', $store ) {

            $this->_node_ids = array();
            $current_module = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
            $page_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id');

            // get all the cms page nodes not folder or containers
            $nodes = Mage::getModel('enterprise_cms/hierarchy_node')->getCollection()
                                                                    ->joinMetaData()
                                                                    ->addFieldToFilter( 'level', 1 )
                                                                    //->addFieldToFilter( 'menu_visibility', 1 )
                                                                    ->addFieldToFilter( 'main_table.page_id', array( 'notnull' => true ))
                                                                    ->setOrder('sort_order','ASC');

            if ( $store instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Store ) {
                $store = $store->getId();
                $storeIds = array( 0, $store );
                $nodes->getSelect()
                      ->joinLeft( array( 'cs' => 'cms_page_store' ), 'main_table.page_id=cs.page_id', array( 'cs.store_id' ) )
                      ->where( 'cs.store_id IN ('. implode( ',', $storeIds ) .')' ); // not the best sql here but it works as store id will be one at a time.
            }

            $active_node = Mage::registry('current_cms_hierarchy_node');
            $active_node_ids = array();
            if($active_node){
                $xpath = $active_node->getXpath();
                $all = explode( '/', $xpath );
                foreach ( $all as $index ) $active_node_ids[] = $index;
            }
            $this->_node_ids = $active_node_ids;
            if ( $this->_menus ) {
                $menus = $this->_menus;
            }
            else {
                $menus = array();
            }

            $links = '';
            foreach ( $nodes as $node ) {
                $tree = $node->setCollectActivePagesOnly(true)
                             ->setCollectIncludedPagesOnly(true)
                             ->setTreeMaxDepth(0)
                             ->setTreeIsBrief(1) //this way it won't show the container link
                             ->getTreeSlice(0, 1); //up to tree top and down to one level
                $links .= $this->drawCmsMenu($tree,0,1,$childrenWrapClass);
            }
            foreach ( $menus as $menu ) {
                if(isset($menu['sub'])) $has_sub_class = ' parent'; else $has_sub_class = '';
                if (isset($menu['module']) && $current_module == $menu['module'] ) {
                    $links .= '<li class="level0 level-top active'.$has_sub_class.'">';
                }
                else {
                    $links .= '<li class="level0 level-top'.$has_sub_class.'">';
                }
                $html = '';
                if(isset($menu['sub']) && is_array($menu['sub'])){
                    $submenu = $menu['sub'];
                    $html .= '<div class="'.$childrenWrapClass.'"><ul class="level0">';
                    foreach($submenu as $sub){
                         if(is_array($sub) &&isset($sub['href']) && isset($sub['label']))
                                                        //2012-11-20 AU TEAM coding for change <h2> -> <span>
                            $html .= '<li class="level1"><a href="'.Mage::getBaseUrl().$sub['href'].'"><span>'.$sub['label'].'</span></a></li>';
                    }
                    $html .= '</div>';
                }
                if(isset($menu['href']) && isset($menu['label']))
                    $links .= '<a class="level-top" href="'.Mage::getBaseUrl().$menu['href'].'"><span>'.$menu['label'].'</span></a>';
                //add submenu
                if($html != '') $links .= $html;
                $links .= '</li>';
            }
            return $links;
    }

    /* Add Maximal Depth filter
     * 2012.04.11 by Bruce
     */
    public function drawCmsMenu( array $tree, $parentNodeId = 0, $level = 0, $childrenWrapClass = '' ) {

        $html = '';

        if ( !isset($tree[$parentNodeId ])) return $html;

        foreach ( $tree[ $parentNodeId ] as $nodeId => $node ) {
            /* @var $node Enterprise_Cms_Model_Hierarchy_Node */
            $nested = $this->drawCmsMenu( $tree, $nodeId, $node->getLevel()+1, $childrenWrapClass);
            $hasChildren = ( $nested != '' );
            // set style classes
            $class = array();
            $class[] = 'level'. ( $level - 1 );
            if ( $level - 1 == 0 )
                $class[] = 'level-top';
            if ( $this->_node_ids && in_array( $node->getNodeId(), $this->_node_ids ) )
                $class[] = 'active';
            if ( $hasChildren )
                $class[] = 'parent';
            // li wrapper header
            $html .= '<li class="'. implode( ' ', $class ) .'">';
            $html .= $this->_getNodeLabel( $node, $level - 1 );
            // div wrapper header
            if ( $hasChildren ){
                if ( $childrenWrapClass ) $html .= '<div class="'. $childrenWrapClass .'">';
                $html .= '<ul class="level'. ( $level - 1 ) .'">';
            }
            // children
            $html .= $nested;
            // div wrapper footer
            if ( $hasChildren ) {
                $html.='</ul>';
                if ( $childrenWrapClass ) $html .= '</div>';
            }
            // li wrapper footer
            $html .= '</li>';
        }
        return $html;

    }

    protected function _getNodeLabel($node,$level)
    {
        if($level==0) $class = 'level-top'; else $class = '';
        if($node->getPageTitle()) return '<a class="'.$class.'" href="'.$node->getUrl().'"><span>'.$node->getPageTitle().'</span></a>';
        else return '<a class="'.$class.'" href="'.$node->getUrl().'"><span>'.$node->getLabel().'</span></a>';
    }
}
```

I know that the config file for this module looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Fvzzy_Category>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Fvzzy_Category>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <fvzzy_category>
                <class>Fvzzy_Category_Block</class>
            </fvzzy_category>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <navigation>Fvzzy_Category_Block_Navigation</navigation>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
        <resources>
            <fvzzy_category_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Fvzzy_Category</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </fvzzy_category_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

And that if I'm able to remove the following part from that file, I get my intended outcome:

```
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <navigation>Fvzzy_Category_Block_Navigation</navigation>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
```

The problem is, I just want to get the top navigation menu function restored back to normal for **one** website view.

1. Is there any way to overwrite that navigation rewrite event for one store/website view?
2. If not, is it possible to disable this module without it disabling my whole top menu for that website view?

I've tried completely duplicating the module, disabling the original one and enabling the new one in my desired website but that also appears to be making the top menu disappear entirely.

I'm really not sure what else to do with this - if anyone is able to help it would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want this extension still for your Magento application, then disabling the extension will not produce expecting result.

In this case, you can do two things

1. Overwrite this custom extension with your module and make changes according to your need
2. comment out the config section that defines that core block overwrite. You have already tried it and worked it
3. There is another alternative. You can do a condition checking inside the rewrite block class. This condition check somewhat look like this.

   ```
     if(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()== 'website_code_for_sub_site'){

           //execute existing code 
     }
   ```

This method ensure that, the method that defined inside the rewrite block class will get executed only when the site with a code `website_code_for_sub_site` is viewing.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks so much your reply - this helped immensely. I'm working on implementing these overrides through a getStoreConfigFlag call but for the time being this solved my immediate problem.

Comment: happy to help you. Out of 3 methods that I provided, which one used by you ?

Comment: I ended up expanding on the principle behind number 3 and instead of relying on store view, added a config area in the admin panel to manage the rewrite, e.g.:

        if(Mage::getStoreConfig('fvzzy_category_config/top_navigation/display_cms_menu') == 1){ return $html; } else { return false; }

Comment: got. This is what I need.. You get idea from my answer and applied it your own way. Keep it up.